# numpy arange implementation on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, like so,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0.5, 0.2],
                   'b': [1,1,0.3]})
print (df)
     a    b
0  0.0  1.0
1  0.5  1.0
2  0.2  0.3
```

I want to generate a Series that looks like

```
pd.Series ([np.arange ( start = 0, stop = 1, step = 0.1), 
 np.arange ( start = 0.5, stop = 1, step = 0.1),
 np.arange ( start = 0.2, stop = 0.3, step = 0.1)])

0    [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, ...
1                            [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
2                                                [0.2]
dtype: object
```

I am trying to do this with a lambda function and getting an error, like so

```
foo = lambda x: np.arange(start = x.a, stop = x.b, step = 0.1)
print (df.apply(foo, axis =1))

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 10), indices imply (3, 2)
```

I am not sure what this means. Is there a better/correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) with `Series` constructor:

```
s = pd.Series([np.arange(x.a, x.b, .1) for x in df.itertuples()], index=df.index)
print (s)
0    [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, ...
1                            [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
2                                                [0.2]
dtype: object
```

---

```
s = pd.Series([np.arange(x.a, x.b, .1) for i, x in df.iterrows()], index=df.index)
print (s)
0    [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, ...
1                            [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
2                                                [0.2]
dtype: object
```

With apply works only converting to `tuple`:

```
foo = lambda x: tuple(np.arange(start = x.a, stop = x.b, step = 0.1))
print (df.apply(foo, axis = 1))
0    (0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, ...
1                            (0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)
2                                               (0.2,)
dtype: object
```

Comment: tolist() works and removes the error. However, it converts the dtype of the float64 and gives imprecise numbers

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a comprehension

```
pd.Series([np.arange(a, b, .1) for a, b in zip(df.a, df.b)], df.index)

0    [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, ...
1                            [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
2                                                [0.2]
dtype: object
```

Comment: For me, this is much faster than the solution provided by @jezrael. It's a factor of 50 compared to `itertuples` and factor 5 compared to `iterrows` variant.